# Create object with Date value

Tags: swift, class, date, swift5, init

I want to create person with property type Date. I created the  extension Date, i expected that i m able to use Date in my object.

```
 extension Date {
  
    func toDate(format: String = "dd/MM/yyyy")-> Date?{
        do{
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE") //
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: format)
            return date
        }
        catch{
            return nil
       }
    }
}
```

my class Person:

```
class Person{
    
    var name: String
    var height: Double
    var birthday: Date

    /// Initializer for the class Person
    init(name: String, height: Double, birthday: Date) {
        self.name = name     
        self.height = height
        self.birthday = birthday
    }
}
```

Object:

**`var`** `person = Person(name: "Ania", height: 20, birthday: "02/02/1998")`

I cannot create a object with Date, my result is :

`Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Date'`

I try rewrite the extension Date, I dont know what i did wrong

Comment: But you never call your extension function...? And your init takes a Date and not a String and why is that function even created in an extension of Date, maybe as an extension to String would be better and then as a computed property instead of a function.

Comment: Your code compiles fine, although see the comment above. Note also: the compiler warning that you're getting in your extension -- you never use `try`, so you don't need your `do` and `catch` block

Comment: how can i extend date, beacuse  i dont know how i can creat object with Date. How i can change my type in birthday to Date

Comment: Shouldn't your extension be on String, not on Date, so you can say `"02/02/1998".toDate(format: "02/02/1998")`? That is, you're starting with a String, and you want to get a Date out

Comment: @Alexander you mean format “dd/MM/yyyy”

Answer (score 0):

If you want use the mentioned constructor above,

```swift
var person = Person(name: "Ania", height: 20, birthday: "02/02/1998")
```

you should add an extension to date to be expressible by string as below

```swift
extension Date: ExpressibleByStringLiteral{
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        self = dateFormatter.date(from: value) ?? .init()
    }
}
```

```swift
var person = Person(name: "Ania", height: 20, birthday: "02/02/1998")
print(person.birthday) // 1998-02-01 22:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Hardcoding the locale is unnecessary with that date format.

Comment: @HangarRash you are right, i just copied the date conversion code above.

Comment: This will create a new date formatter every time you call it